# Shorten both ends of a line with one key

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

Consider the following snippet:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\ptRad{2pt}
    \fill (0,0) circle (\ptRad);
    \fill (1,1) circle (\ptRad);
    \draw[<->, shorten <=\ptRad,shorten >=\ptRad] (0,0) -- (1,1);  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is there a way to use only *one* shortening key for both ends at the same time?

Comment: @Jake: This is for sure nicer then my code. Should I understand from this that there is no build in way (at least currently) to shorten both end at once?

Comment: Yes, at the moment there is no built-in key for this.

Comment: [`pstricks`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks) provides this shortening via the single key `nodesep`. Separate end shortening can be set using `nodesepA` (for the source) and `nodesepB` (for the target).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can define your own style that sets the `shorten` for both ends at the same time:

```
\tikzset{ shorten <>/.style={ shorten >=#1, shorten <=#1 } }
```